# Trouble understanding maven modules and parent projects

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to figure out how to structure my project for Maven, and I've become a little confused.

If I have a Project A, that can be distributed and used on its own, but then I have Project B (which can also be distributed on its own) which depends on Project A and sort of 'builds off' of Project A, should is be a module of ProjectA ? Then Say I have project C, which depends on project B, should that be a module of project B?

I guess I'm confused about how a multi-module project works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maven you can't have cycle dependencies. So in my opinion it would be better to create modules that will not depend on each other (or only on project API) and one that will have dependencies from all others. You need logically structurize them, every module must have some purpose.

For example, module A will have your project API, module B will contain project core (and have dependency on A), module C will have some other purpose, some independent classes that you can use (and have dependencу on A), module D will have other functionality (and have dependency on A) and so on. Then, you can create moduleE, that will have dependencies on B C, D and will use functionality from these projects, will contain user interface and will be the main one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for a short description then I would advice you to look at chapter 7 in Maven by Example:
http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/pdf/mvnex-pdf.pdf